# connect from within android application to a pc via usb to access MS sql database

Tags: android, sql-server, database, sqlite, usb

i have searched every where but could not find an answer,

i need to write an application on an android device, where there is an option for the user when click update button to send data from the application sqlite db (on the device) to the main db (ms sql) on the pc, but this needs to be done using usb connection only (no wifi, no bluetooth and no internet).

i know how to write the sql queries ( read / write / update functions), but i dont know how to connect (from within my application via usb) to the pc( and to the ms sql db on it) and update it(the db on pc hold old data that needs to be updated with new data from device).

if any one can point out some sample code or any suggestions will be very appreciated.

thanx in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Comment: thx for your answer, but this is not what i need, please read my question carefully.

Comment: @user173488 Do you got ans of your posted question? I am facing same problem. I need to send My Scanned data to Desktop having MSSQL server over USB cable only.

Comment: Actually no, the client changed the requirement, and we ended up writing to a file.